# Convert PDF to Word

Tags: c#, .net

Я хочу конвертировать pdf файл в word файл,и для этого использую библиятеку PDFFocus. После конвертирования библиотека от себя добавляет ненужную страницу и еще какие то background штуки, которые я не могу удалить.

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто знаком с этой проблемой или с этой библиотекой. Как мне решить эту проблему?

**Обновление**

Текст добавляемой страницы

```
"The trial version converts only 3 pages. Evaluation only.
Converted by PDF Focus .Net 5.4.5.26.
(Licensed version doesn't display this notice and converts the whole PDF document!)"
```

И еще какие то background надписи, которые даже вручную не могу удалить из уже созданного документа.

Comment: Уточните, что за "ненужную страницу и еще какие то background штуки".

Comment: Купите полную версию программы.

Comment: а как вообще можно удалить эту ненужную страницу с помощью C#?допустим у меня есть файл и я хочу удалить последнюю страницу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112707/) рассматривали различные библиотеки для C#, которые могут работать с pdf файлами. Возможно Вы сможете найти для себя что-то подходящее. По этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246137/itextsharp-trimming-pdf-documents-pages) можете посмотреть пример по удалению страницы с помощью библиотеки iTextSharp.

Comment: большое вам спасибо,Вы мне  помогли!